# Primefaces LayoutUnit does not expand when browser window is maximised

Tags: html, jsf, primefaces

I have a Layout consisting of a north LayoutUnit containing a banner, a west LayoutUnit containing a vertical menu, and a central Layoutunit containing the main page content.

When I open a page with the browser minimised (e.g. browser width is half of the pc screen width) then it displays as much as it can in the view. However, if I then maximise the browser, it doesn't expand the content in the central LayoutUnit (see attached picture).

[image: Browser maximised]

The code for the Layout is as follows:

```
<h:body>
<p:layout style="margin: 0px; gutter: 0px !important!" fullPage="false" >

    <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="80" resizable="false" closable="false" collapsible="true" gutter="0" >
    <div style="background-image: url('../resources/images/veges.jpg'); height: 80px; "> </div> 
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="210" resizable="false" closable="false" collapsible="false" gutter="0">
        <h:form id="menuForm">
        <p:menu style="width:180px">
            <p:menuitem value="Home" outcome="WelcomeMember" icon="fa fa-home" />
        </p:menu>
        <p:menu style="width:180px" toggleable="true">
            <ui:include src="menu.xhtml" />
        </p:menu>
        <p:menu style="width:180px">
            <p:menuitem value="Sign Out" action="#{loginBean.doLogout()}" icon="fa fa-sign-out" />
        </p:menu>
        </h:form>
    </p:layoutUnit>

    <p:layoutUnit position="center" collapsible="false" resizable="true" gutter="0" >
        <ui:insert name="pageContent" >
            This is the default page content
        </ui:insert>
    </p:layoutUnit>

</p:layout>
</h:body>
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and what I need to do to correct it?

Comment: You have `fullPage="false"`, so why should it expand?

Comment: If I set fullPage="true" then I can't scroll down to the see the whole menu which is quite deep

Comment: Then make sure the **content** is scrollable...